# Have other countries (besides Iraq) issued arrest warrants for some [former] US presidents?

Tags: united-states, comparative-politics, iraq, extradition

*The New Arab* reported [that](https://www.newarab.com/news/iraq-affirms-strategic-partnership-us-combating)

> Last year [2022], Iraq's judiciary issued an arrest warrant for former US president Trump for ordering the assassination of Soleimani and Muhandis.

Did the judiciary in any other countries take such a step (despite the low probability of success), i.e. issue an arrest warrant for a sitting or former US president?

Answer (score 9):

[Iran also issued an arrest warrant](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-middle-east-53223523) for Donald Trump (and 35 others) related to the Soleimani killing.

Somewhat related is that Georgia (the US state not the country) [issued an arrest warrant](https://www.the-independent.com/news/world/americas/us-politics/trump-arrest-warrant-georgia-indictment-b2393096.html) for Donald Trump (and 18 others) in connection with the 2020 election.

Answer (score 3):

Within Europe, I believe the closest we have come is the complaints filed against several high-level government officials (I can't remember if George W. Bush himself was included or not) in Belgium after the Abu Ghraib scandal broke.

Like many countries, Belgium asserts universal jurisdiction over certain particularly heinous crimes such as crimes against humanity and war crimes. However, these complaints were never investigated, let alone arrest warrants issued.

An arrest warrant in Belgium would be a lot more politically "interesting" than one in Iraq or Iran, since Belgium is the seat of NATO, the EU Commission, the Council of Europe, and some other important international organizations that high-level US officials might have legitimate need to visit in person.

Answer (score 1):

> Iran said it will pursue a war-crimes case against U.S. president
> Donald Trump at the International Criminal Court in the Hague.[258] On
> 29 June 2020, Iran issued an arrest warrant against U.S. President
> Donald Trump and asked Interpol for help: Tehran prosecutor Ali
> Alqasimehr accused Trump and 30 others of "murder and terrorism
> charges" for the killing of Qasem Soleimani. The request was rejected,
> however, as Interpol constitution forbids it to undertake "any
> intervention or activities of a political, military, religious or
> racial character".[259] On 5 January 2021, Iran asked for another
> Interpol notice against Trump and 47 others for their roles in the
> killing;[260] it was rejected on the same grounds.[261]
>
> On 7 January 2021, Iraq's judiciary issued an arrest warrant against
> Trump, accusing him of "premediated murder", due to his role in the
> deaths of Qasem Soleimani and Abu Mahdi al-Muhandis.[262]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination_of_Qasem_Soleimani

Iraq, Iraq and the U.S. are the only country. The U.S. never indicted any former president before Trump, but Clinton and Nixon were close to be indicted, but the U.S. never did this in order to ensure an orderly transition of power.

Comment: I think your use of the word "indicted" is wrong.  Perhaps you mean "Impeached".  Clinton was impeached, but cleared in the Senate trial (there was never the slightest doubt that the Senate would vote to acquit). Nixon was not impeached, but resigned.